Locality of closed immersions of schemes
Let $(\varphi,\varphi^\#):(X,O_X)\to (Y,O_Y)$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $V\subset Y$ be an open set, and $U:=\varphi^{-1}(V)$. Choosen $x\in U$, the diagram below commutes: $\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD} 
(O_Y)_{\varphi(x)} @>>> (\varphi_* O_X)_{\varphi(x)}@>>> (O_X)_x\\
@VVV @. @VVV \\
(O_Y|_V)_{\varphi(x)}@>>> (\varphi_* (O_X|_U))_{\varphi(x)}@>>> (O_X|_U)_x 
\end{CD}$$
Knowing that the vertical arrows are ring isomorphisms, I'd say that: for any $x\in X$, the composition of ring maps in the upper row is surjective iff there is an open set $\varphi(x)\in V\subset Y$ such that the composition in the lower row is surjective.
Moreover, I think that this fact of topological nature holds too: the continuous map $\varphi:X\to Y$ is a closed immersion iff, for any $x\in X$, there is an open set $\varphi(x)\in V\subset Y$ such that the induced map $\varphi^{-1}(V)\to V$ is a closed immersion.
The two facts in italics together imply that: $(\varphi,\varphi^\#)$ is a closed immersion iff, for any $x\in X$, there is an open set $\varphi(x)\in V\subset Y$ such that ($*$) the induced morphism of schemes $(U,O_X|_U)\to (V,O_Y|_V)$ is a closed immersion, where $U=\varphi^{-1}(V)$.
However I know that the latter italic fact is not true, because there should be instead an open set $y\in V\subset Y$ satisfying ($*$) for any $y\in Y$, not only those in the image of $\varphi$.
May you help me see where is the fallacy? Thanks for any clarification

Your second fact in italics is false for the same reason. The property of being a closed immersion is local on the codomain, i.e. $\varphi\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion iff, for any $y\in Y$, there is an open set $y\in V\subseteq Y$ s.t. $\varphi^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V$ is a closed immersion.
You can already see this principle fail purely topologically. If $X$ is a top. space and $U\subseteq X$ an open but not closed subset, then the inclusion $\varphi\colon U\hookrightarrow X$ is not a closed immersion. However, for any $u\in U$, you find the open set $u\in U\subseteq X$ s.t. $\varphi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is the identity of $U$ and thus a closed embedding. The same logic still works if you replace top. spaces with schemes.

To add to this, the terminology describing this phenomenon is that the property of being a closed immersion is "local on the target" but not "local on the source."
